# Efficiently grouping a list of coordinates points by location in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, grid

Given a list of X,Y coordinate points on a 2D grid, what is the most efficient algorithm to create a list of groups of adjacent coordinate points?

For example, given a list of points making up two non-adjacent squares (3x3) on a grid (15x15), the result of this algorithm would be two groups of points corresponding to the two squares.

I suppose you could do a flood fill algorithm, but this seems overkill and not very efficient for a large 2D array of say 1024 size.

Comment: When are two points adjacent? Depending on your requirements, a shortest path algorithm working with the euclidean distances may be work just fine.

Comment: Two points are adjacent when they are within 1 unit of each other. So (2,2) is adjacent to (2 +/- 1, 2 +/- 1). How would a shortest path algorithm be used?

Comment: Hm, I hadn't thought it through; you would need n^2 time to create the graph, but you can just do the naive pairwise check in that time as well. I don't really see how you can group according to that notion though; you can end up with points that belong to multiple clusters, but maybe that's intended.

Comment: You couldn't have a point adjacent to two clusters, because then that would be a single cluster, unless I'm incorrect.

Comment: Oh, you mean it propagates? As in, if you have (0,0), (1,0) and (2,0), they all belong to the same group even though the distance between (0,0) and (2,0) is 2? Then I definitely misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hash all coordinate points (e.g. using dictionary structure in python) and then for each coordinate point, hash the adjacent neighbors of the point to find pairs of points that are adjacent and "merge" them. Also, for each point you can maintain a pointer to the connected component that that point belongs to (using the dictionary structure), and for each connected component you maintain a list of points that belong to the component.

Then, when you hash a neighbor of a point and find a match, you merge the two connected component sets that the points belong to and update the group pointers for all new points in the union set. You can show that you only need to hash all the neighbors of all points just once and this will find all connected components, and furthermore, if you update the pointers for the smaller of the two connected components sets when two connected component sets are merged, then the run-time will be linear in the number of points.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it works nicely for blocky shapes, but snaky shapes tend to get erroneously split into two groups. Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/eranimo/5be49e8f058c7a0a0392

Answer (score 9):

Fundamentally, this is an image processing operation.  If you use an image processing library like [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#label) (a.k.a. `skimage`), it will be easy.  Dealing with really huge data will eventually get slow, but 1024x1024 is nothing.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import skimage.morphology
In [3]: x = [0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,-3,-2,-1,-3,-2,-1,-3,-2,-1]
In [4]: y = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,-3,-3,-3,-2,-2,-2,-1,-1,-1]
In [5]: dense = np.zeros((9,9), dtype=bool)
In [6]: dense[y,x] = True

In [7]: print(dense)
[[ True  True  True False False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True]
 [False False False False False False  True  True  True]]

In [8]: labeled = skimage.morphology.label(dense)
In [9]: print(labeled)
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2]]

In [10]: coords_yx = { i: (labeled == i).nonzero() for i in range(1,labeled.max()+1) }
In [11]: coords_yx
Out[11]:
{1: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])),
 2: (array([6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8]), array([6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8]))}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you mean by "groups of adjacent" coordinate points. Your example of two non-adjacent 3x3 squares suggests you are looking for what is called [**connected components labeling**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

There are many implementations to extract connected components. Below are a few for guidance.

1. [cclabel](https://github.com/spwhitt/cclabel)
2. [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)
3. [bwconncomp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html)

However, I've implemented this kind of blob detector and they are not that hard to write up if you are looking for a learning experience. If not, then I would go with the most mature library like OpenCV and use their Python API if that's all you need.

Also, you mentioned "efficiency". Note that there are single-pass and double-pass version of these algorithms. Single-pass, as the name suggests, is generally more efficient as it only requires a single pass through our data. This might be needed if your grids are very large.

Comment: Do you know what the time complexity of the implemented algorithms is?

Comment: I haven't analyzed those algorithms implementation. I have used the MATLAB function but it was for a small problem where throughput wasn't an issue. However, a single pass implementation should not require more than O(V+E), where V=Vertices, and E=Edges. For a grid implementation, as you pass through the coordinates, all you have to do is inspect its adjacency to the coordinates behind you. That should be linear and quite efficient.

Comment: The OP states he has coordinates on a grid. A grid is a graph. Albeit a very specialized graph. The coordinates define the vertices and their adjacency defines the edges. If it is in a grid (if I understand the OP questions correctly) you don't have to sort the coordinates.

Comment: ...I had completely overlooked that. I'll be deleting this one and my last comment, soon. Even so, he only says they are on a grid, not that he has them as a grid graph.